# MKPolygon Intersection Point

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpolygon

I'm drawing a polygon on an `MKmapView` like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D  points2[[swaping count]];
points2[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[swaping objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[swaping objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
points2[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[swaping objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[swaping objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
points2[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[swaping objectAtIndex:2] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[swaping objectAtIndex:2] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
points2[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[swaping objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[swaping objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

poly2 = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points2 count:4];
[self.mapView addOverlay:poly2];
```

And after that I can drag my points. I want to know how to check intersection(edge) of poly lines on my polygon?

Comment: And for example my swaping array is:` {
        lat = "37.804333";
        lng = "-122.271105";
    },
        {
        lat = "37.80658";
        lng = "-122.269689";
    },
        {
        lat = "37.805664";
        lng = "-122.267468";
    },
        {
        lat = "37.803494";
        lng = "-122.268798";
    }
)
`

Comment: Not sure if you meant you *can* or *cannot* by saying *cann*.

Comment: can) And after moving point i can recive intersection lines in Polygon. How can I check this edge? or intersection of lines?

Comment: Ok, I just re-edited your post to fix minor grammatical mistakes you had. I'm not sure about the answer, but will post if something comes to my mind. (: